# Error convering character value to monthly data with as.yearmon (zoo)

Tags: r, zoo

Problem occurs when months' value are in the text form like "Jan" or "January".
for example, the following line

```
as.yearmon("Jan-2000", "%b-%Y")
```

returns an error:

```
Error in charToDate(x) : > character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

what's going wrong here?

sessionInfo():

R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Russian_Russia.1251  LC_CTYPE=Russian_Russia.1251    LC_MONETARY=Russian_Russia.1251
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=Russian_Russia.1251

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
 [1] RODBC_1.3-6         latticeExtra_0.6-24 lattice_0.20-10     gplots_2.11.0       MASS_7.3-22
 [6] KernSmooth_2.23-8   caTools_1.13        bitops_1.0-4.1      gdata_2.12.0        gtools_2.7.0
[11] RColorBrewer_1.0-5  xts_0.8-6           zoo_1.7-8

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.15.1

Comment: Works for me with R-2.15.1 and zoo_1.7-7.  Please add the output from `sessionInfo()` to your question.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably connected to LC_TIME locale settings (thanks Joshua for asking sessionInfo() output that tipped for the solution). 
So changing time locale helps.

```
loc <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME") #save current locale for future restore
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
as.yearmon("Jan-2000", "%b-%Y")
```

the result is

> [1] "Jan 2000"